# What does this AWS CloudFormation AWS::Amplify::App Exception mean "Invalid request provided: Repository provider not supported."?

Tags: amazon-web-services, repository, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

I cannot find a single article/example of this scenario but here is what I am attempting to do. I want to create AWS Amplify infrastructure using a AWS CloudFormation template (yml). I have defined the following Resources in the yaml template:

1. AWS::IAM::Role
2. AWS::Amplify::App
3. AWS::Amplify::Branch
4. AWS::Amplify::Domain

When running the `aws cloudformation create-stack ...` command, CloudFormation fails with the following exception ("Invalid request provided: Repository provider not supported."):

[image]

I cannot find a single internet search match for "Repository provider not supported". I am using an AWS CodeCommit Repository url (not github):

amplify-cloudformation-template.yml
[image]

[AWS > CloudFormation > AWS::Amplify::App](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-amplify-app.html)

[image]

Any help on resolution would be appreciated for myself and I am sure the community since AWS has not provided any examples on their official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go to your CodeCommit Repository and click on Clone URL > Clone HTTPS. This will provide you with a link similar as below

```
https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/AmplifyApp
```

You can use the same in your CloudFormation template in the property Repository. Below is the example:

```
MyApp:
    Type: AWS::Amplify::App
    Properties: 
      Description: Test
      Name: Test
      IAMServiceRole: !GetAtt AppServiceRole.Arn
      Repository: https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/AmplifyApp
```